# Possible to rename independent variable name in Built-in lmfit fitting models?

Tags: python, lmfit

I am using lmfit to do small angle X-ray scattering pattern fitting. To this end, I use the Model class to wrap my functions and to make Composite Models which works well. However, it happened that I wrote all my function with `'q'` as the independent variable (convention in the discipline).  Now I wanted to combine some of those q-functions with some of the built-in models. It clashes, because the independent_variable for those is `'x'`. I have tried to do something like `modelBGND = lmfit.models.ConstantModel(independent_vars=['q'])`, but it gives the error:

> ValueError: Invalid independent variable name ('q') for function
>   constant

Of course this can be solved, by either rewriting the built-in function again in `'q'`, or by recasting all my previously written functions in terms of `'x'`. I am just curious to hear if there was a more straight forward approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think that is possible.
I think you will have to rewrite the functions to use `q` instead of `x`.  That is, `lmfit.Model` uses function inspection to determine the names of the function arguments, and most of the built-in models really do require the first positional argument to be named `x`.